# The configuration section 'bundleTransformer' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got this error in asp.net mvc. My code is below:

```
 <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <css>
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
    </translators>
    <postProcessors>
      <add name="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor" type="BundleTransformer.Core.PostProcessors.UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor, BundleTransformer.Core" useInDebugMode="false" />
    </postProcessors>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".css" assetTypeCode="Css" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </css>
  <js>
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
    </translators>
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    </minifiers>
    <fileExtensions>
      <add fileExtension=".js" assetTypeCode="JavaScript" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </js>
</core>
</bundleTransformer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed below nuggets and problem resolved:
(do to this link: [BundleTransformer LibSass Could not be found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770578/bundletransformer-libsass-could-not-be-found-error))

```
Install-Package BundleTransformer.SassAndScss
Install-Package BundleTransformer.Autoprefixer
Install-Package LisSassHost
Install-Package LibSassHost.Native.win-x64
Install-Package JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8
Install-Package LibSassHost.Native.win-x86
```